# How to use HD and SD sprites in Unity addressables

Tags: unity, sprites, spritesheet, asset-workflow, addressable

I am able to load sprites using Unity addressables. But how can I use SD or HD variants of a sprite based on my device resolution?

Previously I was using LIBGDX, and [it has `ResolutionFileResolver` to handle this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916207/8523378).